# Dependable (or not?) random variables on a two-step experiment.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\large\text{W}$e have that $\:\color{teal}k\:$ mint candies and $\:\color{orange}\ell\:$ mango candies belong to a special jar.

We then proceed to pick $\:m\:$ candies from that jar, one after the other and with replacement.$\left(\:m\geq\color{teal}k\:+\color{orange}\ell\:\:\right)$

Let $\:N\::\:$ the number of mint candies we've picked up.$\:\:\:\:\:\:\{\:N\sim B\imath n\:(m,\frac{\color{teal}k}{\color{teal}k\:+\color{orange}\ell})\}$

$f(\eta)=\mathbb{P}\:${$N=\eta$}$\:=\large\binom{{\:\color{teal}k\:+\color{orange}\ell}\ }{\eta}\:(\frac{\color{teal}k}{\color{teal}k\:+\color{orange}\ell})^{\eta}\:(\frac{\color{orange}\ell}{\color{teal}k\:+\color{orange}\ell})^{m-\eta}$

$\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\to M_N(t)=E\:[e^{tN}]=\large(\frac{\color{teal}k}{\color{teal}k\:+\color{orange}\ell}$$e^t\:+\frac{\color{orange}\ell}{\color{teal}k\:+\color{orange}\ell}\:\large)^m$$\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\to M_N'(t)=m\:\frac{\color{teal}k}{\color{teal}k\:+\color{orange}\ell}\:e^t\:\:\large(\frac{\color{teal}k}{\color{teal}k\:+\color{orange}\ell}$$e^t\:+\frac{\color{orange}\ell}{\color{teal}k\:+\color{orange}\ell}\:\large)^{m-1}$$\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\to M_N''(t)=m\:(m-1)(\frac{\color{teal}k}{\color{teal}k\:+\color{orange}\ell}\:e^t)^2(\frac{\color{teal}k}{\color{teal}k\:+\color{orange}\ell}$$e^t\:+\frac{\color{orange}\ell}{\color{teal}k\:+\color{orange}\ell}\:\large)^{m-2}$$+M_N'(t)$

Thus, $M_N'(0)\equiv E\:[N]=m\:\frac{\color{teal}k}{\color{teal}k\:+\color{orange}\ell}$

$Var[N]\equiv M_N''\:(0)-\left(M_N'(0)\right)^2=\:...\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:=\:...\:\:$$=\large[$$m\:(m-1)\:(\frac{\color{teal}k}{\color{teal}k\:+\color{orange}\ell})^2+m\frac{\color{teal}k}{\color{teal}k\:+\color{orange}\ell}\large]$$-\left(m\:\frac{\color{teal}k}{\color{teal}k\:+\color{orange}\ell}\right)^2=m\:\frac{\color{teal}k}{\color{teal}k\:+\color{orange}\ell}\:\frac{\color{orange}\ell}{\color{teal}k\:+\color{orange}\ell}=\frac{m\:\color{teal}k\:\color{orange}\ell}{\:(\color{teal}k\:+\color{orange}\ell)^2}$

Now, we know how this experiment behaves in terms of the binomial distribution.

On a second step, we toss a fair coin as many time as we collect mint candies and we let $\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:X\:: \:$the number of tails

$E\:[X]=\:$?$\:\:\:\:$Now, most reasonably I put a condition on $\:X\:$ such that :

$E\:[X]=E\:[E\:[X|N]\:]=\large\sum_\limits{\eta\:=\:0}^m$$ E\:[X|N=\eta]\:\mathbb{P}\{N=\eta\}$

But would$\:E\:[X|N=\eta]=\frac{1}{2}\:\frac{m\:(m+1)}{2}\:\to E\:[X]=\frac{m\:(m+1)}{4}\large\sum_\limits{\eta\:=\:0}^m\binom{{\:\color{teal}k\:+\color{orange}\ell}\ }{\eta}\:(\frac{\color{teal}k}{\color{teal}k\:+\color{orange}\ell})^{\eta}\:(\frac{\color{orange}\ell}{\color{teal}k\:+\color{orange}\ell})^{m-\eta}$

That is, $\:E[X]=\frac{1}{4}\frac{{m^2}(\:m+1\:)}{\color{teal}k\:+\color{orange}\ell}\:\to Var[X]\equiv E\:[X^2]-E^2[X]=\frac{m\:(m+1)(2m+1)}{6}-\frac{m^4(m+1)^2}{\:(\color{teal}k\:+\color{orange}\ell)^2}$

Now, if everything's right, I need to deduce $f(x)=\mathbb{P}\:\{X=x\}\equiv \text{pmf}_X$ from the moment generating function of $X$. That is, use $M_X(t)$ to find $f(x)$.

How to proceed in such way?

Thanks!

Comment: The expression for $f(n)$ is not right, there is no sum involved.

Comment: Ok thanks but how would that binomial density behave?

Comment: Then for $E(X)$ you can use a conditional expectation calculation.

Comment: Ok great ! But for$\:f(\eta)\:$if there is no sum involved, how would we cover up all possible $\:m\:$ selections of our expirement if, I presume, all those potential selections of picking up candies are mutually exclusive of one an other?

Comment: For the pmf of $N$ there is no sum involved. For the pmf of $X$, there is initially a sum involved, as in the brief answer by BGM. If you then look closely at the sum nice things will happen. It is not clear exactly what you are looking for about $X$, I assume its distribution, or is it just its mean?

Comment: For the pmf of $X$ and its mean it's understood, but merely for the expression of $f(\eta)$ at the top of the page and of wich you said wasn't properly written, I just want to know what would you write instead? Is it about just clearing the sum? If so, why is it that? Thanks!

Comment: It's just $\binom{m}{n}p^n(1-p)^{m-n}$ where $p=k/(k+l)$. But you know this very well.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write down the pmf of $X$, you just need to know

$$X|N = n \sim \text{Binomial}\left(n, \frac {1} {2}\right)$$

and we have
$$ \Pr\{X = x\} = \sum_{n=0}^m \Pr\{X = x|N = n\}\Pr\{N = n\}$$